# Setting URL for Django Translation

Tags: python, django

I have two flag icons and I am willing to give them URLs to determine which language should be displayed using Django translation. Though, I am kind of confused about this. How may I do such a thing?
To be more specific, when the client clicks on Iran's flag, the language prefix in the URL should be changed to 'fa-ir' ([www.domain.com/fa-ir/products](http://www.domain.com/fa-ir/products))

HTML:

```
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-lg-none ml-auto mr-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'products'%}"><div class="ukflag mr-1"></div></a>
            <a href="fa-ir/{% url 'products' %}"><div class="irflag"></div></a>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Products.Views.py:

```
          from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class ProductPageView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'products.html'
```

URLs.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from home.views import HomePageView
from products.views import ProductPageView
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns 
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path("", HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path(_('products/'), ProductPageView.as_view(), name='products'),
    prefix_default_language = False
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to provide a language selector you could do something like this;

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_available_languages as languages %}

<form action="{% url "set_language" %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="language" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    {% for language in languages %}
    <option value="{{ language.code }}"
        {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ language.name_local }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

When you select a choice & the request hits that `set_language` view the system will activate the chosen language. Then when you view a page you'll see things like links prefixed with the current language.

Then to take that logic & apply it to your markup, maybe you could use the language code to set your flags?

```html
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-block d-lg-none ml-auto mr-3">
          {% for language in languages %}
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="{% url 'products'%}"><div class="{{language.code}}flag mr-1"></div></a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

The links in the form will point at the activated language, e.g. `/en/products/`. This is why, in a language selector you wouldn't use `i18n` to display the choices, because you want them to be specific to a speaker of that language & not translated into the current language.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the {{language.code}} as it does not work as a class and as a result, it does not show any flags on the website.

Comment: Turns out I have to grab the class names using {{language.0}}. Though, both of the anchor tags refer to '/en-us/products'

Comment: It won't automatically show flags. My point was that you can use the language codes in your CSS or something to show flags.

Comment: Of course. as I said in the second comment, I got that :) however, the issue is about setting language prefixes in the URL in order to change language when each of the flags is clicked. as both of the anchor-tags are pointing 'en-us/products'

Comment: I'll update my answer, it's a bit too much for a comment.

Comment: I would like to apologize for replying again and taking your time. As I'm a newbie, I'm still confused about the proper solution to set language from an anchor tag. I looked up on django's documentation and some tutorials but yet... would you mimd being a bit more specific? I apologize again

Comment: Put the form at the top of my answer into your page & it will allow you to change the language.